# Difference between std::lock_guard and #pragma omp critical

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, openmp, mutex

Let's consider some code to safely increment a variable in a *for* loop with multiple threads.

To achieve this you have to use some kind of lock mechanism when incrementing the variable.
When I was searching for a solution I came up with the following to solutions.

My questions are:

1. Are they equally good or does one of them has some fallbacks?
2. When to use a `mutex` instead of `#pragma omp critical`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int someVar = 0;
    std::mutex someVar_mutex;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(someVar_mutex);
        ++someVar;
    }

    std::cout << someVar << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int someVar = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        ++someVar;
    }

    std::cout << someVar << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a matter of principle, mixing two different parallelism models if a **bad** idea. So if you use OpenMP parallelism, avoid using the C++ one as interactions between the two might be unexpected. Now, that said, what are you trying to achieve? Because depending on what you want to do with your `someVar`, there might be much better ways of incrementing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The critical section serves the same purpose as acquiring a lock (and will probably use a lock internally).

1. `std::mutex` is standard C++ feature whereas `#pragma omp critical` is an OpenMP extension and not defined by the standard.
2. The critical section names are global to the entire program (regardless of module boundaries). So if you have a critical section by the same name in multiple modules, not two of them can be executed at the same time. If the name is omitted, a default name is assumed.  ([docs](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#CriticalConstruct)).

Would prefer standard C++, unless there is a good reason to use the other (after measuring both).

Not direct targeting the question, but there is also another problem with this loop: the lock is executed on each loop iteration. This degrades performance significantly (look also at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043467/why-is-the-execution-of-2-threads-slower-than-that-of-1-thread-in-c/66043620#66043620)).

Comment: One that thing that should be noted: "#pragma omp critical" can only interact with other "critical" constructs. You cannot mix C++ locks and OpenMP locks (lock API or "critical" constructs) with C++ locks like std::mutex.  So, you there's code that is protected using std::mutex (or std::lock_guard on top), then other OpenMP code that should be mutual exclusively needs to also use std::mutex (and vice versa).

Regarding performance: C++ and OpenMP both over a zoo of lock implementations, so you usually should see very similar performance if you choose similar lock implementations.

Answer (score 5):

From `cppreference.com` about [lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) one can read

> The class lock_guard is a mutex wrapper that provides a convenient
> RAII-style mechanism for owning a mutex for the duration of a scoped
> block.

and from the `OpenMP` standard about the [critical](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf) one can read:

> The critical construct restricts execution of the associated
> structured block to a single thread at a time.

So, both mechanism provide means to deal with the same problem *i.e.,* ensure the [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) of a block of code.

> Are they equally good or does one of them has some fallbacks?

Both are coarser grain locking-mechanisms, however, by default, the OpenMP `critical` is even more coarser grain since:

> All critical constructs **without a name** are considered to have the same unspecified name.

Therefore, if a name is not specified all critical regions use the same global lock, which would be semantically the same as using `lock_guard` with the same `mutex`. Nonetheless, one can along with the `critical` *pragma* specify a name:

> An optional name may be used to identify the critical construct.

```
#pragma omp critical(name)
```

Specifying the `name` on a `critical` is semantically similar to passing the lock to  `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(name);`.

Worth nothing that OpenMP also offers explicitly locking mechanism such as [omp_lock_t](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse31.html) (some details in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396430/how-to-use-lock-in-openmp)).

Notwithstanding, whenever possible you should aim for finer grain synchronization mechanism than a critical region, namely [reduction](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html), [atomics](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu95.html) or even using data redundancy. For instance, in your code snippet, the most performance approach would have been to use the `reduction` clause, like so:

```
#pragma omp parallel for(+:someVar)
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    ++someVar;
}
```

> 2. When to use a mutex instead of #pragma omp critical?

IMO this should never be a consideration, first because as pointed out by none other then [Michael Klemm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2785280/michael-klemm):

> One that thing that should be noted: "#pragma omp critical" can only
> interact with other "critical" constructs. You cannot mix C++ locks
> and OpenMP locks (lock API or "critical" constructs) with C++ locks
> like std::mutex. So, you there's code that is protected using
> std::mutex (or std::lock_guard on top), then other OpenMP code that
> should be mutual exclusively needs to also use std::mutex (and vice
> versa).

and furthermore as [Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5239503/gilles) pointed out (which I also shared the same opinion):

> As a matter of principle, mixing two different parallelism models is a
> bad idea. So if you use OpenMP parallelism, avoid using the C++ one as
> interactions between the two might be unexpected.